# how to make an iframe scroll to specific item

Tags: jquery, iframe, html, scroll

HI,
I have an `iframe` (in my domain) and i am looking for a plugin or any other way that i will be able to do that the iframe window will scroll somewhere in side him ( to a specific div), with a click on a button out side of the iframe.
any ideas?
any one for help??

Comment: i used this plugin but didnt work with iframe 'view-source:http://demos.flesler.com/jquery/scrollTo/'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`iframe`s can be scrolled like any other scrollable element. But you need to be aware that it's a nested document (so offsets are relative to the top/left corner of the iframe + if you want the position of a div in the iframe, you must use `$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv")`)